# Core Data fetch unique property

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a core data object called `Item`, it has 2 properties `identifier` and `type`

```
Item
----

identifier 
type (A/B)
```

It is possible to have 2 items with the same identifier but with different type.

I need to fetch all the items with one condition:
if two items has the same identifier, only show the A type.

In other words I want to make sure that the fetched items will have a unique identifier, and in the case of multiple items with the same identifier, priority will be given to item with type A.

I also prefer not to use `NSDictionaryResultType` if possible

Answer (score 1):

You can fetch from Core Data with a predicate to find (or count) objects with an `identifier` (btw do **NOT** use `id`, it is a reserved word in Cocoa) and you can sort by another property and then you can limit your fetch result to a single item.

That will give you your priority you are looking for.  However, I strongly recommend against handling the issue that way and instead writing your creation code to avoid having duplicates in the first place.

### Update

What I am saying is that you **can't** "fetch all the items with one condition...".  What you **can** do is fetch *per item* (using the identifier), limiting the fetch to a single result sorted by `type` which will give you your results.

If you wanted all items of type "a", that is doable.

If you wanted all items and filtered on type in a second pass in memory, you could do that

You cannot combine them.

Now, if you want to fetch per item, filtering on the type it would look like this:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *moc = ...;
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"MyEntity"];
[fetchRequest setFetchLimit:1];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"identifier == %@", myIdentifier];

NSSortDescriptor *sort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"type" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sort];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortArray];

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *results = [moc executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
if (!results) {
  NSLog(@"Error: %@\n%@", [error localizedDescription], [error userInfo]);
  abort();
}

id mySingleObject = [results lastObject];
```

**NOTE:** This code was written in the browser, there are probably errors.

Comment: sorry but i didnt understand your solution, limit my fetch to single item? but I want all the item, only remove the duplicate. I'm not sure I know how to do all those thing you talk about, can u please give an example?